# when compute method is called in Fork/Join framework in Java

Tags: java

```
pool.execute(task); 
pool.execute(task);
```

I use these two method to test Fork/Join framework but I don't know when the compute method is called. Can you help me ? Thanks !

Comment: `execute` will call it...